# JavaScript for loop is pushing duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, duplicates, iteration

I originally used for/of, like so:

```js
for (let item of totalData) {
    if (item) {
        let comp1 = item.slice(0,item.length/2)
        let comp2 = item.slice(item.length/2)
        for (let char of comp1) if (comp2.includes(char)) {
            arr.push(char)
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that I was getting the wrong results, so I started console logging the `char` and the `item`. This led me to notice that there were items in the first array (`totalData`) for which this code was running multiple times.

Thus, I tried doing it the original way, changing it to `for (let i = 0; i < totalData.length; i++)` and assigning `item` as `totalData[i]`. This didn't change anything.

Finally, I tried this code:

```js
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < totalData.length; i++) {
    let item = totalData[i];
    if (item && item != totalData[i - 1]) {
        let comp1 = item.slice(0,item.length/2)
        let comp2 = item.slice(item.length/2)
        for (let char of comp1) if (comp2.includes(char)) {
            arr.push(char)
            console.log(char,item)
        }
    }
}
```

It came out with seemingly just as many (97, although I guess I didn't check how many there were before) duplicates.

Is this a bug in devtools or did I do something wrong? I'm using Brave (Chromium) devtools to run this code.

Edit: to make this more reproducible, here's my full code with a fake array (because the array I'm using is way too long)

```js
let totalData = ['testingt','stringhere','doesntmatttr'];
let arr = [];
for (let item of totalData) {
    if (item) {
        let comp1 = item.slice(0,item.length/2)
        let comp2 = item.slice(item.length/2)
        for (let char of comp1) if (comp2.includes(char)) {
            arr.push(char)
        }
    }
}
console.log(totalData.length, arr.length)
```

Running this in my console, I got 3 and 5. Here's a screenshot of what happened with the data I was originally using:

[image: A devTools console with a lot of gibberish strings printed out, some of which have numbers next to them to indicate duplicates]

Those strings (minus the characters at the beginning, those were the results) all appeared in my dataset, but only once each.

Edit 2: I'm trying to figure out what characters in each string are on both sides of it. The expected output for the example I gave (the `arr`) would be `['t','r','t']`.

Comment: Whatever else is wrong, `char` should be declared with `let`

Comment: Please include an [mre] (i.e.  You need to provide data, and what's wrong with the output)

Comment: If i understand correct, objective is to just get a list of characters that have more than 1 count. Correct?

Comment: Unclear what the desired result array is, please provide an example input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out while responding to people because it made me look at the question more from an objective viewpoint rather than from the viewpoint of someone who's tryna make the code work.
The problem is that some of the strings in my data array (e.g. "cNzPBNpclllzHbmTNRhqCRTgjC") have a character on the first side of the string twice, and also have it on the second side. So, for this string, it would push "N" twice, because it's checking for each character in the first side of the string (so both Ns) whether or not one exists on the second side (and there is an N on the second side).

Fixed code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < totalData.length; i++) {
    let item = totalData[i];
    if (item && item != totalData[i - 1]) {
        let comp1 = item.slice(0,item.length/2)
        let comp2 = item.slice(item.length/2)
        for (let char of comp1) if (comp2.includes(char)) {
            arr[i] = char
        }
    }
}
```